# jQuery/Javascript: HTML pulled in by AJAX request does not include <script> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dynamic page which uses an AJAX request kicked off by jQuery to pull in HTML elements from the server and insert them into the DOM.

The problem is that when I have  elements within the response, they are stripped out.

For instance, if I request the following from the server:

```
<!-- content.html -->
<div>
    There is some content here!
    <script>
        manipulateContent();
    </script>
</div>
```

What actually gets injected into my dynamic page is the following:

```
<!-- content.html -->
<div>
    There is some content here!
</div>
```

I have tested in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari with identical results.

The relevant Javascript which creates the AJAX request is here:

```
function loadContent(url){
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    if (a.search == ""){ 
        url = url + "?trim=true";
    } else {
        url = url + "&trim=true";
    }

    var ch = $('#content-container').height();
    // var wh = $(window).height();

    $("#content").animate({top: '-='+ch+'px'}, 500, function(){
        $.get(url, function(data){
            $("body").scrollTop(0);
            $("#content").html(data);
            $("#content").css({top: ch+'px'});
            $("#content").animate({top: '0px'}, 500);
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    // get the current path and save it for later
    var currentPage = location.pathname+location.search;

    $(".content-link").live("click", function(){
        // using the HTML5 history API, add the requested path
        // to the browser history, then load the new content
        history.pushState({ path: this.path }, '', this.href);
            // because the page is not reloaded, $(document).ready()
            // is not called, so the currentPath must be updated manually
                currentPage = this.href;
        loadContent(currentPage);

        return false;

    });

    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
        // compare the current path to the one being loaded
        // if they are different, then load the content
        // else, nothing happens
        if (currentPage != location.pathname+location.search){
            // because the page is not reloaded, $(document).ready()
            // is not called, so the currentPath must be updated manually
            currentPage = location.pathname+location.search;
            loadContent(currentPage);
        }
    });

});
```

How can I tell jQuery to include the  tags in the response? I've tried browsing through the jQuery docs without much luck, or even mention of the fact that the  tags are stripped out. Perhaps I'm just not looking in the right places.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), since the whole purpose here is to load hml content to a element.

```
function loadContent(url) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    if (a.search == "") {
        url = url + "?trim=true";
    } else {
        url = url + "&trim=true";
    }

    var ch = $('#content-container').height();
    // var wh = $(window).height();

    $("#content").animate({
        top : '-=' + ch + 'px'
    }, 500, function() {
        $("#content").load(url, function() {
            $("body").scrollTop(0);
            $("#content").css({
                top : ch + 'px'
            });
            $("#content").animate({
                top : '0px'
            }, 500);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: $.load() appears to strip <script> tags as well. I'll do more research and get back to you.

Comment: As per the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution) it should not be happening

Comment: The behavior appears to be opposite to the docs. When I make a `$.load('content.html')` request, scripts are stripped, but when I request `$.load(content.html #content)`, the scripts are not stripped. I think I am misinterpreting the docs or misusing jQuery.

Comment: can you share the contents of `content.html`

Comment: I don't actually have a `content.html`. I've been using that name for the sake of example. I've designed my server-side code to allow the AJAX requests to load in arbitrary html from the server. In this case, for the sake of testing, I made sure to try loading a document which has an element with id of `content` and script tags within that element.

edit: upon further testing, I cannot reliably get `$.load()` to retain script tags with either method.

Comment: It seems to be working fine in [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/vWIySD5ZDRCDuECa8K72?p=preview), can you try recreating the issue

Answer (score 1):

According to jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if `dataType` option is `html`:

> Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when
>   inserted in the DOM.

By default this option is set to `Intelligent Guess`, so you may want to check the type of response from the server.

Comment: I tried setting the dataType parameter to both `string` and `html`. Both seemed to function identically, but both broke the rest of my script for some reason. This appears to be the best way forward, but I need to figure out why it doesn't cooperate with the callback function.